# Google Apps Script. *Copy* a file

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I've been looking around the site to find a way of actually copying a file using Google Apps Scripts. I found something, however, the file isn't actually copied. What actually happens is a link to that file get's sent to the folder specified. Is there any way to actually copy a file and send that file to a folder using Google Apps Scripts? I can't seem to figure out how to do it, if there is ever a way.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on exactly what it is you want to do; if you just want to make an exact copy:

//Example script:

```
function makeCopy(){<br>
     DocsList.getFileById(<em>the ID of your file</em>).makeCopy().addToFolder(<em>your destination folder</em>);<br>
}
```

**Note**: "your destination folder" listed above designates the Path to the folder. For example, if your dest. folder is the child of a folder after root, your path would be `Root/Parent/Child`, e.g. `Stuff1/Stuff2`. (The `Root` folder is not included here as the system recognizes it automatically as the root folder.